# Is there a 'text or user reference' module?

Tags: 7, users, entities, forms

Currently, I'm planning on using a text field for full names (added fields `field_profile_full_name` and `field_profile_partner`) on user entities, so that one user can link to another. However, I might not get matching entries in autocomplete (which rules out user references). What I want is this:

1. A match to text entered in `field_profile_partner` is found in `field_profile_full_name`: return/use the text in `field_profile_full_name`.
2. A match is not found: use the text the user entered in `field_profile_partner`, without creating a new user.

I know that a '[text or node reference](https://drupal.org/project/text_noderef)' module exists for Drupal 6 and 7, but I've been unable to find a module that does the same thing for user references. Does such a module exist or will I have to clone and adapt 'text or node reference'? Can I configure [entityreference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) to give me this functionality?

**Note:** I know that I could write a custom form and autocomplete page to handle this, but the functionality needs to be on the user account/registration form. If this can be done in `hook_form_alter`, please provide it as I've had no luck getting that hook to work whenever I implement it on anything.

Answer (score 1):

The [Entity reference](https://drupal.org/project/entityreference) module will relate any Drupal entities. These include:

- Nodes
- Users
- Taxonomy Terms

So should be perfect for your needs.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I've never used entity reference before, so this might be a stupid question. Will it allow me to create references to custom/add-on fields (not just core fields such as username)?

Comment: It allows you to create "entity reference fields". This field type can be added to any entity and it is this field that holds the relationship. So no, you can't use existing fields.